# How to format outputof floats so they have two places after decimal point?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, python-3.6

this should be a very simple issue but I'm having a tougher time than expected on it. I want to have my floats be turned into strings but only to the 2nd decimal place. what I have works except with a few values that decide to extend more than 2 decimal points . Below is what im currently trying:

```
for i in range(len(self.monthlyData)):
        t = self.monthlyData[i] * 100
        '{0:.2}'.format(t)
        t = str(t) + " %"
        self.monthlyData[i] = t
```

I would want my values to be the decimals followed by the % sign. so I would want it to look like this "19.58 %" and like I said it works with most values but some values like 29.080000000000002 and stay like that.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `'{0:.2}'.format(t)`.

Comment: It should also probably be `'{0:.2f}'`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do the task:

```
for i in range(len(self.monthlyData)):
    t = '{0:.2%}'.format(self.monthlyData[i])
    self.monthlyData[i] = t
```

But seriously, you do not have to loop through a `pandas` column to revise the values. A nicer approach would be the `apply` method with `lambda`:

```
self.monthlyData.apply(lambda x: '{0:.2%}'.format(x))
```

You can find more information at the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)